# How do you loop music in PyGame Subset for Android?

Tags: android, loops, pygame, playback

I've been trying to get music to loop in my Android game written with PyGame Subset. This is what I have so far and it only plays the audio file once. I would really like to use the built-in looping function so that way I don't have to loop the audio manually using a timer. Any ideas?

```
import pygame
try:
    import pygame.mixer as mixer
except ImportError:
    import android_mixer as mixer
if mixer:
    mixer.music.load("woo.mp3")
    mixer.music.play(-1)
while True:
    if mixer:
        mixer.periodic()
```

Answer (score 1):

Note does not work in Android 5.x. I know this is an old post but I have a also encountered this problem. zenopython's answer will work with some tweaking as there is a mistake in the mixer module. If you look in the anroid.mixer module and look at the music class you will see.

```
@staticmethod 
def get_busy(): 
    return music_channel.get_volume()
```

as you can see this actually calls get_volume() which always returns 1.0. To fix this I copied the mixer.py file into my game directory and changed this to

```
    @staticmethod
    def get_busy():
        return music_channel.get_busy()
```

Then imoport mixer and it works. SO something like

```
import pygame
try:
    import pygame.mixer as mixer
except ImportError:
    import mixer
if mixer:
    mixer.music.load("woo.mp3")
    mixer.music.play(-1)
while True:
    if mixer:
        if mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
            mixer.music.play(-1)
```

That worked for me.

As mentioned above this does not work in an 5.x.

Another solution is to simply queue music which does work

```
mixer.music.load('music')
mixer.music.play()
mixer.music.queue('music')
```

In general the mixer.music module in [pgs4a](http://pygame.renpy.org/) has a number of errors. Another error I found is in the mixer.music.pause() and mixer.music.unpause(). unpause() just calls pause() again so I also had to edit this to allow pausing the music when the game is stopped. See below

```
if android:                                                         
    if android.check_pause():
        mixer.music.pause()
        android.wait_for_resume()
        mixer.music.unpause()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this instead of music.load():

To create a new Sound object from a file

```
mixer.Sound(filename): return Sound
Sound.play(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that the problem can be solved with mixer.music.get_busy() which returns a bool value, True if music is playing, False if there is no music playing.

```
import pygame
try:
    import pygame.mixer as mixer
except ImportError:
    import android_mixer as mixer
if mixer:
    mixer.music.load("woo.mp3")
    mixer.music.play(-1)
while True:
    if mixer:
        if mixer.music.get_busy() == False:
            mixer.music.play()
```